# On his left or to his left

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> John entered the hall. **On/to** his left was a table.
>
> John saw that **to/on** his left was a table.

On Google, I found more results with "to", but I guess that doesn't make "on" wrong. To my ear, "on" refers to a more generic position, and closer to the subject, whereas "to" refers to a precise direction, that might be very distant. Another example:

> On/to his left was a mountain.

To me "on" sounds like the mountain is closer, almost towering the subject. "To" instead make the mountain farther from him. Am I correct? If not, what are the differences? In which contexts one is preferable over the other?

Comment: One more: *at someone's left!*

Answer (score 2):

There is no big difference, and you have already googled (though the 'general' search is not that reliable!) and found out that 'to' is more. There's nothing to say more on that.

I [checked Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+his+right+was%2Con+his+right+was&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6) and carefully read many examples for both the phrases. There's no difference at all. Both phrases have been used to denote a person, a thing, a big thing, and all such entities. So, don't bother much. They both are the same in almost all contexts.

But, personally, I'd prefer writing *to,* because we are talking about a *direction.*

Comment: (–1) Native speakers would probably disagree (see the question this one's a duplicate of). Also, if you have already introduced extra options (*at*), please explain when you'd use them, because that's only muddying the waters.

Comment: @userr2684291 - I'm a native speaker, and I don't disagree. As for that question you've linked to, it has one answer that merely speculates how "to your left" may be considered a bit more leftward than "on your left," but even that is described as more of a personal opinion than a hard-and-fast rule. Many learners seem to struggle with the idea that we can sometimes use two (or even three) different prepositions in a sentence with virtually no change in meaning, and the OP's "John saw a table _____ his left" is one good example, as this answer aptly points out.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for clarifying. However, first of all, I think there's always a difference, because otherwise people wouldn't continue using two expressions; one would have to fall out of favor at some point. That's how language, and everything in general, works, by my lights. Native speakers generally have trouble **articulating** subtleties of their native tongue. Sometimes, as might well be the case with the linked answer, such explanations are merely impressions.

Comment: @J.R. I hope you understand I was simply swayed by one such explanation given by a native speaker of English. Google Books Ngram Viewer results are really not much of an indicator either because you'd have to **see** what the book is describing in order to register any differences, regardless of how many results there actually are, favoring one or the other preposition. This answer is bad because it relies on these hits and somehow presupposes the asker has doubts as to what kind of object (i.e., what size, etc.) is located *to* or *on* someone's right/left side.

Comment: @J.R. The answer further concludes with some vague notion about direction. I don't understand how anyone might upvote this answer as the sole thing it does after stating an opinion is invite doubt. Nothing in this answer apart from the needlessly and inconsistently reiterated opinion reinforces any singular notion the answerer might have concerning this issue.

Comment: @userr2684291 - I don't buy that there's "always" a difference, or that one preposition is destined to "fall out of favor." Consider, for example: _talking **on** the phone_ vs. _talking **over** the phone_; or _a book **about** politics_ vs. _a book **on** politics_. As long as dictionaries define prepositions with other prepositions, there will be some cases with more overlap than difference. The word _on_ can mean "with" (no money on/with me); the word _with_ can mean "against" (wrestle with/against demons); the word _against_ can mean "from" (protection against/from disease), and so on.

Comment: @userr2684291 - RE: _Google Books Ngram Viewer results are really not much of an indicator either you'd have to see what the book is describing in order to register any differences._ Yes, and this answer specifically states: "I carefully read many examples for both the phrases." (Ngrams will let you do that, if you use the links on/at the bottom of the page.)

Comment: @J.R. Just so we're clear, I'm not trying to nitpick or anything; I simply disagree with what you're saying. Because I speak a language natively myself and am aware that when people say "X and Y mean the same thing", they're not exactly the same. And English can't be any different because it's a language and no two different words or expressions mean the same. Only in the language of mathematics may we define things to be equivalent, and even then we talk of some sort of equivalence, equipollence, bijection. But, OK, you can *define* things to be equivalent. Dictionaries don't actually define.

Comment: @userr2684291 - Exactly. There's a big difference between "there is no big difference" (what this answer says) and "they are exactly the same" (what your comment says). There's also a big difference between "X and Y mean the same thing" (what you said) and "X and Y _can_ mean the same thing" (what I said). That's why there's not "always" a difference (what you said).

Comment: @J.R. Hm, okay, I see what you mean. I misread what you said. Feel free to bin all of these comments.